# Eonasdan Bootstrap Datetimepicker not working properly when I click on the calendar icon or input box

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm having a problem with the Eonasdan Bootstrap datetimepicker. I copied and pasted the code from his website (minus the row and container because it made the layout of my panel messy). I suspect that the calendar is buried and not visible for some reason. I was hoping you guys could give me a hand!

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
                <input type="text" class="form-control active" />
                <span class="input-group-addon btn">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    $('#datepicker').off('focus').datepicker().click(
                    function () {
                    $(this).datepicker('show');
                            }
                                );
            </script>
```

and here are my reference files so that you can see that I'm loading them properly.

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="js/bootstrap.min.js">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js">
    <link href="js/moment.min.js">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

I hope you can give me a hand! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to call jquery before all js files.

Second, the click function is working and you can see some part os calendar or you can't view nothing?

Comment: Yes I can see the icon, and click on it, but I can't see the calendar to choose the date.

Comment: As asked in another comment, put your code in jsfiddle and edit your question, so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why you are using

```
$('#datepicker').off('focus')
```

try this out.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                locale: 'ru'
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Ravi, I tried this and it still doesn't work. I can see the icon and when I click on it, I can tell that it registered as me having clicked it. However, I can't see the calendar. Cheers

Comment: can you just create a demo in jsfiddle so that i can get to know actually wats happening please.?